# visual c++ mfc mdi Access violation reading location 0x000fc2f0

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

i am doing a mdi project in visual c++ using mfc
i am using a CArray to save and load data to documents. CArray contains members of a custom class of mine.

Saving and loading works fine

I get access violation when closing a document that i have opened, and debugger points me to carray.

the weird thing is that i can close without problem "new" documents and the program crashes only when i am trying to close a document that i "open".

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: my guess: an object gets deleted twice? can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

debugger points me to that code

i got the message "TYPE not found"

> CArray::~CArray()
>       {
>         ASSERT_VALID(this);
>
> ```
>   if (m_pData != NULL)
>   {
>       for( int i = 0; i < m_nSize; i++ )
>           (m_pData + i)->~TYPE();
>       delete[] (BYTE*)m_pData;
>   }
> }
> ```

what code u want to see exactly?

forgot to mention that if i open an empty document closing is working fine as well

Comment: Why are you explicitly calling the destructor, then deleting it as BYTE-pointer?  I suppose that the delete of the BYTE-pointer does not execute the destructor again?  If it does this, your destructor is executed twice and this can explain your crash (you should verify this).  A better way of writing this is just to "delete[] m_pData".  This will call the destructor of all the instances in your array, and free the memory.

Comment: that code is not mine is the carray destructor in afxtempl.h.

i post it to show where the problem occurs

Comment: That posted code is fine: this is the use of an in-place destructor to call the destructor for TYPE, then the delete[] cleans up the memory. This allows the CArray object to manage the memory for the underlying array as one block.

Comment: At which line in this does the debugger point you? The assertion, or something below it?